# How do I create a supervisor/subordinate relationship between Contacts?

Tags: wordpress, civireport, relationships

I want to produce a report that lists all supervisors and their subordinates. (Assume that all Contacts have supervisors but not all Contacts have subordinates.) I plan to export the report to Excel and then use pivot tables to produce a hierarchical org. chart.  What's the most efficient way for me, a non-coder with no SQL, to create the relationships in CiviCRM and include them in the Columns table of the new report? (CiviCRM 5.58.1 on Wordpress 6.2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a new relationship type, then you can use SearchKit to find contacts with that relationship type and export in a CSV.

Comment: I haven't used relationships before.  Is it correct that for this application I would have to create 2 relationships for each Contact: one to identify the supervisor and one to identify the subordinate(s)?

Comment: No, relationships are bi-directional. When you create 1 relationship between 2 contacts, it exists for both contacts.

Comment: If it helps, think of the relationship as the piece of string that you attach one of the two ends of to each of the two people

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on this. Isn't the particular case that I'm working on (supervisors with subordinates) different than the example of siblings given in the CiviCRM User Guide? I want to identify that John reports to Jane; it's never the case that Jane reports to John. These seem to be uni-directional relationships.  What am I missing? (And thanks from this newbie for considering these elementary questions.)

Comment: Have a look at Child of / Parent of as an example, that's the same as Supervisor of / Subordinate of that you would create. When you create a relationship between two contacts, it is always bi-directional, Bob is the parent of Jill, Jill is the child of Bob, Mark is the supervisor of John, John is the subordinate of Mark (siblings is the same,  Tom is the sibling of Julie, Julie is the sibling of Tom).

Comment: In other words, some relationship types have a direction (A -> B), and others do not (A <-> A) - the only difference between directional and non-directional relationship types is whether you give the same name to both sides.

Comment: So, all relationships are bi-directional; some of them are directional and others are non-directional.  I'd like to find a primer (beyond the CiviCRM User Guide) on creating relationships in CiviCRM.  Does such a think exist? Or is it time to turn to a professional?

Comment: Is the docs on Creating New Relationship Types what you're looking for or is something missing in there?
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/relationships/#creating-new-relationship-types

Comment: Thank you. I have created some directional relationships. I can't figure out how to edit the Contact when there is a re-organization: Jane used to supervise John and now she supervises Bill. When I view Jane's Contact Record and click on Relationships, the pop-up screen shows John's name but there's no way to replace his name with Bill's.

Comment: You'll just want to make inactive or delete the current relationship and create a new one.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't think of that.